# fping Script Described in Man Page has Syntax Error

Tags: perl

I'm trying to run the fping script described in its man page.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
 require 'open2.pl';

 $MAILTO = "root";

 $pid = &open2("OUTPUT","INPUT","/usr/local/bin/fping -u");

 @check=("slapshot","foo","foobar");

 foreach(@check) {  print INPUT "$_\n"; }
 close(INPUT);
 @output=;

 if ($#output != -1) {
  chop($date=`date`);
  open(MAIL,"|mail -s 'unreachable systems' $MAILTO");
  print MAIL "\nThe following systems are unreachable as of: $date\n\n";
  print MAIL @output;
  close MAIL;
 }
```

However, I get the following error from anywhere I run it:

> ```
> syntax error at /path/to/pingtest.pl line 13, near "=;"
> Execution of /path/to/pingtest.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
> ```

Can someone help me what's wrong with line 13?  I have open2.pl and fping path is correct.

Comment: Please link to your source when you are having problems with external information

Answer (score 4):

If you have found the script on the online [man-page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fping), then `<OUTPUT>` has been interpreted as HTML markup and deleted. It should read

```
@output = <OUTPUT>;
```

But this Perl script looks like it was written decades ago

- The use of `require open2.pl` was [long-ago replaced by `use IPC::Open2`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RGARCIA/perl-5.6.2/lib/open2.pl)
- It does not use `use strict` or `use warnings`, and avoids lexical variables
- Function calls use the arcane `&open2` syntax, which is useful only in very special cases
- The calls to `open` use the old-fashioned and ambiguous two-argument-version

Comment: It uses `$#output != -1` to check for an empty array when `@output != 0` (or just `@output`) would be clearer. It uses `chop` instead of `chomp`, blindly removing the last character instead of checking for newline. It shells out to `date` instead of just calling `POSIX::strftime` (or even `localtime` in scalar context).

Comment: All of this makes me think this code was written for perl4, which points to a date of origin somewhere in the early 90s (perl5 was released in 1994).